# Is it possible to avoid local installation and use flat files for WiX?

Tags: msbuild, automation, wix

### Background:

I always try to ensure the following tenet in my projects:

**After a fresh checkout a developer should be able to do all project related tasks with solely the contents of the combined folders.**

Obviously, this isn't always possible (e.g. Visual Studio for Windows development). However, I really dislike having to install any third-party libraries or tools that are specific a project like log4net, NHibernate, NUnit, etc. There are number of reasons for this including:

- For a given development machine, you may work on several different projects, all which leverage different versions of the same third-party library or tool.
- Minimizing the environment setup requirements makes setting up new developers or machines much easier
- Facilitates easier maintenance of automated builds

### Assumptions/Contraints

- I am currently using WiX 3 beta, but if there is way for either 2.0 or 3.0 please respond
- I am using Visual Studio 2005
- The IDE syntax highlighting is not a requirement.

### Question:

Is it possible to avoid local installation of the WiX toolset and use flat files instead? If so, please explain how.

### See Also:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First, build your WiX installer:**

- Create a new WiX Installer Project in Visual Studio 2005.
- Build your WiX XML accordingly.

**Now, to integrate the WiX toolkit into your source tree:**

- Copy `c:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3\bin` to a sub-directory in your source tree.  I used `WiX\bin` relative to my .wixproj file.
- Copy `c:\Program Files\MSBuild\WiX\v3.0\` to a subdirectory in your source tree.  I used `WiX\v3.0` relative to my .wixproj file.
- Either add the following code or replace the line that follows:

`<WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == ''>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.0\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>`

With the following lines:

`<WixToolPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\WiX\bin\</WixToolPath>
    <WixTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\WiX\v3.0\WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
    <WixTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\WiX\v3.0\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>`

As you can see, the `WixToolPath`, `WixTasksPath` and `WixTargetsPath` directives reflect the location of the folders I've instructed you to copy.

- Rename your .wixproj to .csproj.  This ensures that Visual Studio does not get confused by the .wixproj file but because the .wixproj is a valid MSBuild project, Visual Studio will be able to work with it.

Using this method, the WiX directory as described is about 9MB large.

Comment: Sweeeeet. Thanks for the detailed instructions, this worked like a charm.

Comment: You could at least have referenced your source, namely the "Integrating WiX Projects Into Daily Builds" topic in the CHM file that comes with wix.

Comment: @wcoenen: Is that in the CHM?  I actually winged it by reading Wix.targets, finding the compile instruction, determining what the variable was called, and defined them in my parent XML file.

Thanks for the reference though: it's good to know I didn't have to do it the hard way if I'd read the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I know with WiX 2, you can just download the executable files and the dll's to whatever directory your project is in. Then you create a .bat file to run candle.exe and light.exe with the parameters you need to build your installer.

That way, all your projects can have their own version of WiX with a disk drive hit of only about 4 megs each.

I'm not positive, but I think you can do the same with WiX 3.

Comment: I'm going to try this out and see if it works. I'll get back with the results. Thanks Grant!

Comment: Yep, you are able to do it. Antik gave a detailed explanation of it so I accepted his answer but thank you for the assist!